# Does $\forall v ( T_1 v = 0 \lor T_2 v = 0 \lor \dots \lor T_n v =0 )$ imply $T_1 = 0 \lor T_2 = 0 \lor \dots \lor T_n = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, group-homomorphism

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $T_1$, $T_2$, $\dots$, $T_n$ be linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, such that for every $v$ in $V$, either $T_1 v = 0$, $T_2 v = 0$, $\dots$ or $T_n v = 0$. Can we conclude that $T_1 = 0$, $T_2 = 0$, $\dots$ or $T_n = 0$?

**My attempt:**

I could prove the statement for $n = 2$ but I couldn't generalize it, and I also couldn't find any counterexample for greater $n$.

For $n = 2$, suppose $T_1 \ne 0$ and $T_2 \ne 0$. Hence there are $u$ and $v$ in $V$ such that $T_1 u \ne 0$ and $T_2 v \ne 0$. By hypothesis, we must have $T_1 v = 0$ and $T_2 u = 0$ which yield $T_1 ( u + v ) \ne 0$ and $T_2 ( u + v ) \ne 0$, contradicting the hypothesis.

I also noted that my argument for $n = 2$ can be reformulated if $V$ and $W$ were just groups and $T_1$ and $T_2$ were group homomorphisms. So I got interested in the more general problem about groups. (This is in fact another question about which I'm less concerned in this particular post.)

Comment: Are you only considering vector spaces over infinite fields (like the real or complex numbers)? Otherwise the implication does not hold.

Comment: If $V$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space, the claim is true. Notice that the condition is equivalent to saying that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} \ker T_i = V$. But if none of $T_i$ is zero, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} \ker T_i$ is a finite union of nowhere dense set and hence cannot cover $V$. Of course this argument extends to a more general setting. On the other hand, if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field, then certainly the implication is false.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee That seems like a perfectly fine answer to me.

Comment: @Servaes, Thank you. But please let me wait for an answer that does not rely on topological or measure-theoretic argument. I guess my answer is an overkill...

Comment: please in the case of $n = 2$ why you suppose $T_1$  not $0$ and $T_2$ not $0$, may be, I have a problem with the language and thank you

Comment: One can prove that a finite union of proper subspaces of a vector space $V$ over an infinite field can't be all of $V$, without resorting to topology or measure theory. I think Pete Clark was involved in a discussion of this, maybe on MathOverflow, some years ago....found it! http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces

Comment: @m.idaya $\dim V = 2$. If $T_1, T_2$ aren't zero map, then $\text{ker } T_1 = \lbrace \alpha_1 \rbrace$ and $\text{ker } T_2 = \lbrace \alpha_2 \rbrace$ (or empty, but forget it.) Suppose that vectors are linear independent. Take $v = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$. Notice, that $T_1, T_2$ are linear. For $\dim V > 2$ you have similar arguments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, That is what I was looking for! I guess your comment is good to go for an answer.

Comment: Tace et : but not mentiened in the text that $dimV=n$

Comment: @MohsenShahriari countrexample for true claim? #m.idaya For $\dim V > 2$.  Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ be sum of bases of $T_i$. $T_1(v) = T_1(\alpha_2), T_2(v) = T_2(\alpha_1)$... It's not obvious, but you can end this proof elementary. First take base of $\text{ker } T_1 \cap \text{ker } T_2$, then extends to both bases.

Comment: please I can not understand the question help me by explaining
what happens if $T_1=0$ and $ T_2\neq  0$.  it is very
interesting, please take patience with me, and thank you very much

Comment: @m.idaya I was trying to give a backward proof for "$T_1 = 0$ or $T_2 = 0$". I first added the assumption that non of $T_1$ and $T_2$ is the zero transformation. Then I showed that this assumption leads to a contradiction and thus it's false. So either $T_1$ or $T_2$ is the zero transformation and the statement is proven.

Comment: but i think that $T_1=0$ and $T_2\not= 0$ satisfaied the hypotheses

Comment: @m.idaya Well' isn't that an example of what we wanted to prove? We showed that either $T_1 = 0$ **or** $T_2 = 0$. In your case.  we have $T_1 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be the base field. We suppose that $n$ is such that $n+1\leq |k|$.
The hypothesis gives $V = \cup_{i=1}^{n}\ker T_i$.
We show that if $\ker T_1\ne V$ then $V=\cup_{i=2}^{n}\ker T_i$, and so step by step  we get an $i$ such
that $V = \ker T_i$.
Suppose $\ker T_1\ne V$. Then let $x\in \ker T_1$ and $y\in V\setminus\ker T_1$. For $a\in k^\times$ there are at least $n$ different vectors of the form $x+ay\in \cup_{i=2}^{n}\ker T_i$, so there is $i$ such that two different vectors $x+ay$ and $x+by$ are in $\ker T_i$. This shows that $y$ and also $x$ are in $\ker T_i$, therefore $\ker T_1\subseteq \cup_{i=2}^{n}\ker T_i$ and so $V=\cup_{i=2}^{n}\ker T_i$.

Comment: 1) Why $n+1 \leq p$? 2) Why there are n+1 different vectors of form $x+ay$?

Comment: $y\not =0$, so $x+my, m=1,...,p-1$ are different vectors , that is at least $n$